# C# Enyim Memcached - namespace 'Enyim' does not exist. Missing assembly?

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim

Im want to start a new project using memcached with C# and I found the Enyim libraries the best choice, but when I try to use them I get the error:

The type or namespace 'Enyim' does not exist in the class or namespace 'Enyim' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

What I did to set up the environment was:
1. Install-Package EnyimMemcached (with Nuget)
2. Adding "using Enyim."
3. When I compile the project I got the error

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the target framework of your application to *.NET Framework x.x*.

**Not** *Client Profile*. You can do it in project properties/compile/advanced compile options

Comment: I went to project properties/Compile/Advanced but I havent found anything about the .NET Framework XX

Comment: I use visual studio 2010 and in the Application tab I tried to set it from the 2.0 to 4.0 and no one worked. If I go to compile/advanced I found https://twitter.com/#!/Rubertuz/status/199476426477547520/photo/1

Comment: Then it must be something else. Make sure the dlls are referenced by your project. Sometimes (if you have more than one project in a solution) you install the package for the wrong projects (if you click too quickly).

Comment: I use visual studio 2010 and in the Application tab I tried to set it from the 2.0 to 4.0 and no one worked. If I go to compile/advanced I found twitter.com/#!/Rubertuz/status/199476426477547520/photo/1

Comment: I have only one project opened and it's a demo with 4 lines of code

Comment: I did exactly what you did in my test app and encountered exactly the same problem. Changing the target framework from *.NET Framework 4 Client Profile* to *.NET Framework 4* solved this problem. Make sure that target framework in project properties -> application tab is set to the correct one...

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changet it to .NET Framework 4 from the Aplication Tab and it worked!

Comment: Sure you helperd me a lot! DONE ;)